# PC lint error 19 "useless declaration "

Tags: c, static, embedded, error-suppression

I want to understand the solution for the PC lint error 19 "useless declaration". i am using a interrupt vector table, and calling the interrupts with required parameters. when i run for PC lint I am having the error 19 as shown below can some one help me in this ?

## ifndef Int_HandlerIndAddr

#define Int_HandlerIndAddr(Isr, CpuNr, IntNr, Prio) Int_HandlerIndAddr2(Isr, CpuNr, IntNr, Prio)

## endif

```
#define Int_HandlerIndAddr2(Isr, CpuNr, IntNr, Prio) \
__asm__ (".ifndef .intr2.entry.include                        \n"\
        ".altmacro                                           \n"\
        ".macro .int2_entry.2 intEntryLabel, Prio, name # define the section and inttab entry code \n"\
        "   .pushsection .\\intEntryLabel,\"ax\",@progbits   \n"\
        "   __\\intEntryLabel :                              \n"\
        "       bisr    Prio                                 \n"\
        "       movh.a  %a14, hi:\\name                      \n"\
        "       lea     %a14, [%a14]lo:\\name                \n"\
        "       ji      %a14                                 \n"\
        "   .popsection                                      \n"\
        ".endm                                               \n"\
        ".macro .int2_entry.1 IntNr,Prio,CpuNr,u,name           \n"\
    ".int2_entry.2 intvec_tc\\CpuNr\\u\\IntNr,%(Prio),(name) # build the unique name \n"\
        ".endm                                               \n"\
        "                                                    \n"\
        ".macro .intr2.entry name,CpuNr,IntNr,Prio           \n"\
            ".int2_entry.1 %(IntNr),%(Prio),%(CpuNr),_,name # evaluate the priority and the cpu number \n"\
        ".endm                                               \n"\
        ".intr2.entry.include:                                \n"\
        ".endif                                              \n"\
        ".intr2.entry "#Isr","#CpuNr","#IntNr","#Prio      );\
```

function call in the same file  as below

```
Int_HandlerIndAddr(TaskOs_CallTaskApp10ms, 0, ISR_NR_TASK_APP_10MS, ISR_PRIO_TASK_APP_10MS);

Int_HandlerIndAddr(TaskOs_CallTaskApp1ms, 0, ISR_NR_TASK_APP_1MS, ISR_PRIO_TASK_APP_1MS);
```

PC lint error message as below:

```
Int_HandlerIndAddr(TaskOs_CallTaskApp100ms, 0, ISR_NR_TASK_APP_100MS, ISR_PRIO_TASK_APP_100MS);

C:...\0_Src\0_AppSw\Tricore\BSW\Setup\IntVecTab.c 
    107  Error 19: Useless Declaration

C:..\0_Src\0_AppSw\Tricore\BSW\Setup\IntVecTab.c 
    107  Error 19: Useless Declaration

Int_HandlerIndAddr(TaskOs_CallTaskApp10ms, 0, ISR_NR_TASK_APP_10MS, ISR_PRIO_TASK_APP_10MS);

C:......\0_Src\0_AppSw\Tricore\BSW\Setup\IntVecTab.c 
    111  Error 19: Useless Declaration

C:.....\0_Src\0_AppSw\Tricore\BSW\Setup\IntVecTab.c 
    111  Error 19: Useless Declaration
```

Comment: Does this code work at all, given that you left an empty row after the macro? Meaning there's currently no connection at all between the macro and the inline assembler.

Comment: @Lundin: I think that's half my fault - the original post didn't have the code section formatted as code and it looked like it was pasted from some source that "double spaced" it.  I fixed most of that, but I overlooked that blank line.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.gimpel.com/html/pub/msg.txt (emphasis added):

> 19    Useless Declaration  -- A type appeared by itself without
>         an associated variable, and the type was not a struct and
>         not a union and not an enum.  **A double semi-colon can
>         cause this** as in:
>
> ```
>   int x;;
> ```

If you notice, your macro ends in a semi-colon and you add a semi-colon when you invoke the macro.  Therefore the expanded code has a double semi-colon.  Get rid of one of them (I'd suggest the one in the macro definition).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: however my complete code is as below.
#ifndef Int_HandlerIndAddr
#define Int_HandlerIndAddr(Isr, CpuNr, IntNr, Prio) Int_HandlerIndAddr2(Isr, CpuNr, IntNr, Prio)
#endif

#define Int_HandlerIndAddr2(Isr, CpuNr, IntNr, Prio) \
__asm__ (".ifndef .intr2.entry.include                        \n"\
  ".     \n"\
        ".intr2.entry "#Isr","#CpuNr","#IntNr","#Prio      )